# How to solve an inhomogeneous two dimensional ODE system with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} &=
%
-Ax+By+I\\
\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t} &=
%
Cx-Dy\\
\end{align}

With $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=y_0$. Let
\begin{align}
\vec{u}=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right),
%%%
\quad
%%%
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-A & B\\
C & -D
\end{array}
\right),
%%%
\quad
%%%
\vec{I}=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
I \\
0
\end{array}
\right),
%%%
\quad
%%%
\vec{u}(0)=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
y_0
\end{array}
\right),
\end{align}

Where all constants are $>0$. Therefore we can recast the system as
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}\vec{u}}{\text{d}t} = M\vec{u} + \vec{I} 
\end{align}

Let $\mu_+$ and $\mu_-$ be the eigenvalues of $M$. Let the homogeneous solution be given by $\vec{u}_h$ and the partial solution be given by $\vec{u}_p$, such that
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}\vec{u}_h}{\text{d}t} &= M\vec{u} \\
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\vec{u_h}(t)=
%
\frac{y_0}{\mu_2-\mu_1}
%
\left[
%%
\left(\begin{array}{c}
B\\
A+\mu_1
\end{array}\right)
e^{-\mu_1 t}
%%
-
%%
\left(\begin{array}{c}
B\\
A+\mu_2
\end{array}\right)
%
e^{-\mu_2 t}
%
\right]
\end{align}

where
\begin{align} 
\mu_1 &= -\frac12 \left( \text{Tr}(M)+\sqrt{\text{Tr}(M)^2-4\det{M}} \right),
%
\\
%
\mu_2 &= -\frac12\left(\text{Tr}(M)-\sqrt{\text{Tr}(M)^2-4\det{M}}\right),
%
\end{align}

Let
\begin{align}
U(t)=
\frac{y_0}{\mu_2-\mu_1}
%
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
Be^{-\mu_1 t}                     & Be^{-\mu_2 t}    \\
\left(A+\mu_1\right)e^{-\mu_1 t}  & \left(A+\mu_2\right)e^{-\mu_2 t}
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}

Notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}U}{\text{d}t} = M U
\end{align}

Therefore consider 
\begin{align}
\vec{u}(t)=U(t)\vec{v}(t)
\end{align}

Where $\vec{v}(0)=(1,1)^T$

giving
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}\vec{u}}{\text{d}t}
%
&=
%
\frac{\text{d}U}{\text{d}t}\vec{v}(t) + U\frac{\text{d}\vec{v}}{\text{d}t}\\
&=
%
MU\vec{v}(t) + U\frac{\text{d}\vec{v}}{\text{d}t} 
%
=
%
M\vec{u} + \vec{I}
%
=
%
MU\vec{v}+\vec{I}\\
%%
\Rightarrow \quad
\frac{\text{d}\vec{v}}{\text{d}t} &= U^{-1}\vec{I}\\
%%
\Rightarrow \quad
\vec{v}(t) &= \int_0^t U^{-1}(s)\vec{I}\ \text{d}s\\
%%
\Rightarrow \quad
\vec{u}(t) &= U(t) \int_0^t U^{-1}(s)\vec{I}\ \text{d}s
\end{align}

Is this the correct method? Have I got the correct initial conditions for $\vec{v}(t)$

Comment: For a LTI system with a constant inhomogeneous input you will also get an additional constant in the output, which can also be described by a change in coordinates (changing coordinates can give you a homogeneous ODE).

Comment: @fibonatic: changing coordinates sounds like a better way to solve this. A linear change in x and y?

Comment: Yes, a linear change in $x$ and $y$, such that $\hat{\vec{u}}=\vec{u}+\vec{w}$ is the linear transformation of $\vec{u}$ and satisfies $M\vec{u}+\vec{I}=M\hat{\vec{u}}$.

Comment: You can actually do this for any [polynomial inhomogeneity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321179/trouble-with-non-homogeneous-ode-system-which-method-shall-i-use/1322036#1322036).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t)=\text{I}+\text{B}\cdot y(t)-\text{A}\cdot x(t)\\
y'(t)=\text{C}\cdot x(t)-\text{D}\cdot y(t)
\end{cases}
$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
s\text{X}(s)-x(0)=\frac{\text{I}}{s}+\text{B}\cdot\text{Y}(s)-\text{A}\cdot \text{X}(s)\\
s\text{Y}(s)-y(0)=\text{C}\cdot \text{X}(s)-\text{D}\cdot\text{Y}(s)
\end{cases}
$$

So, we can say:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}(s)=\frac{\frac{\text{I}}{s}+\text{B}\cdot \text{Y}(s)+x(0)}{\text{A}+s}\\
\text{Y}(s)=\frac{\text{C}\cdot\text{X}(s)+y(0)}{\text{D}+s}
\end{cases}
$$

Now we can substiute them into each other to get:

- $$\text{X}(s)=\frac{s\text{B}y(0)+(\text{D}+s)(\text{I}+sx(0))}{s((\text{A}+s)(\text{D}+s)-\text{B}\text{C})}$$
- $$\text{Y}(s)=\frac{\text{C}(\text{I}+sx(0))+sy(0)(\text{A}+s)}{s((\text{A}+s)(\text{D}+s)-\text{B}\text{C})}$$

Comment: Thank you for this! Give me a sec to work through it, it's been a couple of years since I used laplace transforms embarrassingly.

Comment: @Freeman You're welcome, I think this the most easy way of solving this LTI system.

Comment: I agree, it is a nice method. I'm just attempting to transform it back, noting x(0)=0.

Comment: "The most easy way of solving this LTI system"... not sure. Because there is as much work for going back into the variable $t$ world ! In particular, due to the not simple discussion between simple and double poles. See my solution. I don't pretend it is shorter than yours ; I just wanted to say that Laplace Transform - that I have used a lot of times - may be more lengthy than it appears at first.

Answer (score 1):

**First point**: as it is an affine system, I transform it into a linear system by looking for constants $u$ and $v$ such that it is equivalent to
$$\tag{1}\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} &=
%
-A(x+u)&+&B(y+v)&&\\
\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t} &=
%
\ \ C(x+u)&-&D(y+v)&\\
\end{align}$$

A rapid computation shows that is possible using

$$\tag{2}u=\dfrac{CI}{BC-AD} \ \ \text{and} \ \ v=\dfrac{DI}{BC-AD}$$

(I have seen afterwards that you have done the same transformation in your solution).

Under the condition that the determinant $AD-BC$ of matrix $M$ is non zero,
we are back to a linear system, that we will rename in the following way:
$$Y'=MY$$
with $Y(0):=(u,y_0+v)^T.$

**Second point**: I directly use the **matrix exponential form** for the solution of this differential system under the form:

$$\tag{3}X=exp(t M).Y(0) \ \ \text{with} \ \ Y(0):=(u,y_0+v)^T$$

Here, we can rely on formulas that can be found in ["Some Explicit Formulas for the Matrix Exponential" IEEE Trans. on Automatic Control, Vol 38, no.8, August 1993](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/2027.42/57871/1/ExponentialExplicitSoTAC1993.pdf) (their corollary 3.3) making of course a distinction between the cases where the two eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of $M$ are equal or different, which corresponds to the fact that the discriminant of the characteristic equation of $M$, i.e.,

$$\tag{4}\delta:=(A-D)^2+4BC$$

is zero or non zero resp.:

- **equal eigenvalues** : $\tag{5}exp(tM)=e^{-(A+D)t/2}\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{A-D}{2}t& Bt\\Ct&1+\frac{A-D}{2}t\end{pmatrix}.$
- **different eigenvalues** :

$\tag{5'}exp(tM)=e^{-(A+D)t/2}\begin{pmatrix}\gamma -\frac{A-D}{2}\sigma t& B \sigma t\\C \sigma t&\gamma +\frac{A-D}{2}\sigma t\end{pmatrix}$ using

$$\tag{6}\Delta:=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\delta}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{(A-D)^2+4BC}, \ \ \gamma:=\cosh{\Delta} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \sigma:=\dfrac{\sinh{\Delta}}{\Delta}.$$

The last straightforward step, that we will not do, amounts  to plug either (5) or (5') into (3), using the values of $u$ and $v$ that are in relationship (2).

Remark: if $\delta<0$, the hyperbolic cosines/sines become naturally circular cosines/sines.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your input, it's nice to see different methods.

Comment: In fact, a good night after i wrote the first solution, I realized that there was a flaw in it (I couldn't write it into the $3 \times 3$ form I gave :-(...). Happily, I found another way to transform it at once into a linear system. For the rest, I think that you will agree that it is still a valuable solution where the two cases (equal and different eigenvalues) are neatly considered.

Comment: Thanks for the update!! Very cool :) I really appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} &=
%
-Ax+By+I\\
\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t} &=
%
Cx-Dy\\
\end{align}

With $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=y_0$. Let us define $M$ as
\begin{align}
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-A & B\\
C & -D
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Now, by the transform on $x$ and $y$ such that
\begin{align}
x(t) &= X(t) + \frac{DI}{\det{M}}\\
y(t) &= Y(t) + \frac{CI}{\det{M}}
\end{align}

the system becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}X}{\text{d}t} &=
%
-AX+BY\\
\frac{\text{d}Y}{\text{d}t} &=
%
CX-DY\\
\end{align}

With
\begin{align}
X(0) = X_0 =    -\frac{DI}{\det{M}},\quad
Y(0) = Y_0 = y_0-\frac{CI}{\det{M}}
\end{align}

Therefore, letting $\vec{U}(t) = (X,Y)^T$
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}\vec{U}}{\text{d}t} &= M\vec{U} \\
\end{align}

Defining the absolute eigenvalues of $M$ as below,
\begin{align} 
\mu_1 &= -\frac12 \left( \text{Tr}(M)+\sqrt{\text{Tr}(M)^2-4\det{M}} \right),
%
\\
%
\mu_2 &= -\frac12\left(\text{Tr}(M)-\sqrt{\text{Tr}(M)^2-4\det{M}}\right),
%
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\vec{U} &= 
%
C_1 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
B \\
\mu_1+A
\end{array}
\right)
e^{-\mu_1 t}
%
%%
+
%%
C_2
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
B \\
\mu_2+A
\end{array}
\right)
e^{-\mu_2 t}
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
B & B \\
\mu_1+A & \mu_2+A
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
C_1 \\
C_2
\end{array}
\right)
%
&=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
X_0 \\
Y_0
\end{array}
\right)\\
%%%%%%%%
\Rightarrow\quad
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
C_1 \\
C_2
\end{array}
\right)
&=
%
\frac{1}{B(\mu_2-\mu_1)}
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\mu_2+A & -B \\
-\left(\mu_1+A\right) & B
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
X_0 \\
Y_0
\end{array}
\right)\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&=
%
\frac{1}{B(\mu_2-\mu_1)}
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(\mu_2+A\right)X_0 - BY_0 \\
-\left(\mu_1+A\right)X_0 + BY_0
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\vec{U} &= 
%
\frac{1}{B(\mu_2-\mu_1)}
\left[
%
\left\{\left(\mu_2+A\right)X_0 - BY_0\right\}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
B \\
\mu_1+A
\end{array}
\right)
e^{-\mu_1 t}
%
%%
-
%%
\left\{\left(\mu_1+A\right)X_0 - BY_0\right\}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
B \\
\mu_2+A
\end{array}
\right)
e^{-\mu_2 t}
\right]
\end{align}

Let us assume that $\mu_1\ll\mu_2$, giving,
\begin{align}
\vec{U} &\simeq
%
\frac{\left(\mu_2+A\right)X_0 - BY_0}{B(\mu_2-\mu_1)}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
B \\
\mu_1+A
\end{array}
\right)
e^{-\mu_1 t}
\end{align}

Therefore by the transformation performed earlier we find that
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
%
&\simeq
%
\frac{\left(\mu_2+A\right)X_0 - BY_0}{B(\mu_2-\mu_1)}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
B \\
\mu_1+A
\end{array}
\right)
e^{-\mu_1 t}
%%
+\frac{I}{\det{M}}
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
D \\
C
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}